# IRIX - can't write, copy or move large files to an NFS share but can write/copy/move small ones

Tags: nfs

Other servers are mounting this NFS share successfully and transferring files of much larger size to it (full machine backups of 8+GB) writing directly to it from bru, but I have two servers which just refuse to write or copy anything fairly substantial in size to it.

All the systems are IRIX6.5

Comment: Could be a largefiles issue, depending on what version of IRIX you have the mount option largefiles (allowing 2Gb+ files) may not be default and you have to manually specify it.

Comment: I have resolved it (but SF won't let me answer my own question for another 6 hours) - although the version of nfs on the working/non-working servers was the same, the kernel is different, leading to some weird inconsitencies.

Adding wsize=4098 to the entry in fstab solved it, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `wsize=4098` to the entry in `fstab` solved it